# How to get total value of odd, even numbers and echo invalid inputs

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the code that I have so far for one of my assignments.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Numbers</title></head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<b>Numbers</b>
<br>
<textarea rows="12" cols="25" name="result" value="result"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $result=$_GET["result"];
    if (empty($_GET['result']))
        {
            echo '<p><font size="3" color="red">Field is Empty*</font></p>';
        }
    elseif (isset($_GET['result']))
        {
            $result=(explode("\n", $result));
        }

    echo "<br />";  
    echo "Total lines passed: " . count ($result);
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Total value of numbers: " .array_sum($result);

?>
```

I need a code to echo out the total values of the even and odd number inputs that are submitted into the textbox. Ex. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are submitted and the total value for even comes out as 6 because of 2 and 4 being even numbers and the total value for odd comes out as 9 because of 1, 3, and 5 being odd. If the user also inputs an invalid integer, let's say a, b, c. I will be able to echo out a list of all the invalid values submitted.

```
1
2
3
4
5
a
b
c

Total of even numbers: 6
Total of odd numbers: 9
Invalid Numbers: a b c
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array_map('trim', $result); // to trim the whitespace in your input
$even = $odd = $invalid = array();

foreach ($result as $num) {        
    if (is_numeric($num)) {
        if ($num % 2 == 0) {
            $even[] = $num;
        } else {
            $odd[] = $num;
        }
    } else {
        $invalid[] = $num;
    }
}

echo "Total of even numbers: " . array_sum($even) . "<br />";
echo "Total of odd numbers: " . array_sum($odd) . "<br />";
echo "Invalid numbers: " . implode(' ', $invalid) . "<br />";
```

[**Demo!**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6kq-8m5)

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$even=array();
$odd=array();
$invalid=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
{
   if(!is_numeric($result[$i])) { $invalid[]=$result[$i]; continue; }
   if($result[$i] % 2 == 0) $even[]=$result[$i];
   else $odd[]=$result[$i];
}
echo "Sum of even numbers: " . array_sum($even);
echo "Number of even numbers: " . count($even);
echo "Sum of odd numbers: " . array_sum($odd);
echo "Invalid numbers: " . implode(",",$invalid);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. If I submit 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 it gives me 0 for even and the last value I entered (in this case it's 5) for the odd

Comment: I fixed it, missed some indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = array("even" => 0, "odd" => 0, "invalid" => 0);

foreach ($result as $r){
    if(intval($r) == "" && $r != 0){
        $total['invalid']++; 
    }else{
        if ($r % 2 == 0){
            $total['even'] += $r;
        }else{
            $total['odd'] += $r;
        }
    }
}

print_r($total);
```

Comment: The odd and even outputs work! for the invalid however, it gives the value of 0. I just need to know how to echo them now. Unless I'm completely clueless.

Comment: @user2896254 Use something like this: http://3v4l.org/io1ur (I was composing an answer, but it looks too identical to this one).

Comment: Wow thanks! I only used the echo codes because I actually didn't know how to output them. :)

Comment: @user2896254: I think the best way is to use `implode()`. Check out my answer. I've included a [demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6kq-8m5) too.

Comment: @AmalMurali Wow! Thanks a whole bunch! I was going to use filter_var and figure it out from there but you just solved my problem! Thanks again!

Comment: @user2896254: If it helped, please consider marking my answer as the [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) solution by clicking on the green checkmark [✓](http://sweetclipart.com/multisite/sweetclipart/files/check_mark_green.png) next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $evenSum=0;$oddSum=0;
    $alphaArr=array();
    foreach($result as $key){
    if(!is_nan($key)){
    if($key%2==0){
    $evenSum+=$key;
    }
    else{
    $oddSum+=$key;
    }
    }else{
   $alphaArr[]=$key;
```